# Azure DevOps Build Pipeline with repository in GitHub

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

UPDATE: I *think* this question was based on a fundamental misunderstanding. When creating the build pipeline definition, I would pick the saved service connection ("GitHub-iQmetrixService" in the screenshot), and then later Azure DevOps would continue to prompt for access to *my personal account*. This made me think that the build pipeline was linked to my personal account somehow, such that if my account is ever in the future gone or otherwise unable to access the repository, the build pipeline would stop working.

As far as I now understand, this is not the case. The build pipeline definition *itself* is in fact associated with the service connection, and the reason that Azure DevOps prompts for my personal login is because the integrated YAML editor is going to want to make commits back to the repo, and those commits need to happen "as me". When co-workers go to the pipeline editor, they too are prompted for their personal login.

I'm still a little bit nervous about this understanding, because I can't see anything in the UI that shows what service connection Azure DevOps is using primarily to process the build pipeline, nor can I see any way to change it should that ever be necessary.

---

When creating a new Build Pipeline, if I tell Azure DevOps that my repository is in GitHub, I am immediately redirected to GitHub to authorize access to my *personal* GitHub account (to which I have an ambient login). If I instead pick "Other Git", then the next step in the flow lets me say that the source is GitHub, at which point the screen says:

[image]

This authorization, set up by someone else in my organization, works just fine, and I can view all of the organization's repositories and set up a new pipeline. But then, if I close the window and try to re-open the pipeline editor, I am immediately redirected once again to the GitHub page to authorize access to my personal account. Editing the pipeline created based on the "GitHub-iQmetrixService" connection does not use the connection and instead wants to establish a new connection based on whatever individual accounts I have access to.

[image]

How can I edit the pipeline without creating a connection to the repository that is linked to my own personal account?

Comment: Just wanted to check in what the status on this issue was? Does session and cookie  which I suggested can help you avoid the authorized manually now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As work around, you can take advantage of the browser **sessions** and **cookies**.

Configure the browser to let it **retain and keep the session**. And do not clear the session and cookie data once you close the browser.

For me, I am using **Edge**. So, I go `Settings` -> `Privacy and Security` -> `Choose what to clear`, then **disable** the option

[image]

After configure this, I do not need input my account, password and Verification code again while I close the windows, re-open and re-edit the pipeline,

---

If you want to make some configuration changes on this pipeline, please go right corner-> three dots, and choose the Triggers.

After located to the Triggers page, please change to `YAML` tab.

[image]

Then you can do the modified on this pipeline

Comment: So, I guess what I wasn't understanding was why Azure DevOps wanted access to _my personal account_. It seemed that the basic processing of the build pipeline was tied to my account. If my GitHub account goes away (or is no longer able to access the repository), will the pipeline continue working? I was confused that my login was still needed even after configuring the pipeline using the stored service connection ("GitHub-iQmetrixService" in the screenshot). But, I now realize that the integrated YAML editor wants to make commits back to the underlying repo, and those need to be "as me".

Comment: @JonathanGilbert. I know this design is very inconvenience during the pipeline. But we are designed based on the **security**. We must ensure the pipeline user is the one who allowed to work with corresponding github repos. I think if you are a github organization owner, you do not want someone who not have work permission can do something on your github repos. That's why we need check the user's identity every time, and let the server knows who you are and whether you can do something on github repos. This all based on the security.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Is there a way to see the service connection the build pipeline is using to actually operate? Can it be edited? I could just be missing it but I don't see it anywhere in the UI. Specifically, I'm wondering if there is something on the build pipeline definition I can drill into that will show the fact that it is using `GitHub-iQmetrixService` to poll for triggers, pull the source to build, etc.

Comment: @JonathanGilbert, if you store the identity in the session or cookie, the server would extract these info from the session. Then send the information to server and let the server whether your identity is available for github.

Comment: Okay, but the point I'm getting at is, the build continues to operate and fire when trigger conditions are met even when I'm not logged in. It's not using my personal account for all that stuff, is it? I mean, it's not receiving any sort of session or cookie when checking a trigger or starting such a build because it isn't associated with anything I'm doing in a browser to begin with. I'm _assuming_ it's using the service connection I picked when I created the definition in the first place? How do I see what that is?

Comment: @JonathanGilbert, of course sure. You can go project setting -> service connection, then you can see the connection. Then combine with the build definition, you would know that which service connection this pipeline is using: https://imgur.com/a/jdYhHV3 . Then you can update the service connection: https://imgur.com/a/gjhpLT5

Comment: I'm not convinced the two circled bits in the first screenshot are actually the same thing. In your case they happen both to be "LiangMengdi", but in my case one of them says "iQmetrix" the name of the GitHub organization and the other is "GitHub-iQmetrixService" the name of the service connection. Stack Overflow is recommending we move this discussion to chat, guess I'll click that and see what happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203888/discussion-between-jonathan-gilbert-and-merlin-liang-msft).

Answer (score 0):

To provide some clarity, it appears what's going on here is that for YAML build definitions, Azure DevOps doesn't actually go to the build pipeline definition editor when you select "Edit". The YAML text editor it takes you to is in place of the build pipeline definition editor. But, the definition editor can still be reached. @Merlin Liang - MSFT's answer provides (after the horizontal rule) the steps to take to do this. I didn't understand *why* those steps, though. I created the following graphic to explain specifically the aspect that wasn't clear in my head:

[image: Comparative flowchart]